# How to add interpolation using webgl vertex and fragment shaders to the image

Tags: javascript, webgl

Hello everyone,
                I am trying to render a image using webgl shaders and I have successfully done that using webgl samples but the issue is that when i increase the size of image the quality of image is not good. I want to upscale and interpolate the image using vertex and fragment shader.[Here is my sample](https://jsfiddle.net/niks2060/jxsmteL4/)

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  var image = new Image();
  requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(image, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Pneumothorax_CT.jpg")
  image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Pneumothorax_CT.jpg";
  image.width = 1000;
  image.height = 1000;
  image.onload = function() {
    render(image);
  }
}

function render(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Create a texture.
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the image into the texture.
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

  // lookup uniforms
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

  webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Clear the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Turn on the position attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

  // Turn on the teccord attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

  // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Draw the rectangle.
  var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
  var offset = 0;
  var count = 6;
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    x1, y1,
    x2, y1,
    x1, y2,
    x1, y2,
    x2, y1,
    x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();


// This is needed if the images are not on the same domain
// NOTE: The server providing the images must give CORS permissions
// in order to be able to use the image with WebGL. Most sites
// do NOT give permission.
// See: http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html
function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) {
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) {
    img.crossOrigin = "";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:700px; width:700px; overflow:scroll;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>


<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec2 a_position; 
  attribute vec2 a_texCoord; 
  uniform vec2 u_resolution; 
  varying vec2 v_texCoord; void main() { 
    // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0 
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution; 
    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2 
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0; 
    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace) 
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0; 
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1); 
    // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader 
    // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord; 
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
 
// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
 
// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
 
void main() {
   // Look up a color from the texture.
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
</script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

I need interpolation when image zoomed or if set by maximum height like AMI exmaple provided below [Check This sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/fnndsc/ami/tree/master/lessons/03#run)

Comment: First, you can change texture parameter from `gl.NEAREST` to `gl.LINEAR`, WebGL will perform filtering for you. Otherwise maybe this will give you some clues: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter27.html

Comment: not of use I have tried but It will not give expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to happen.

First off you set `gl.NEAREST` as your filtering. WebGL has several kind of filtering [covered here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). Setting them to `gl.LINEAR` would be better but only
a little

The problem is WebGL 1.0 doesn't support mips for images that are not power of 2 dimensions (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc...). [That page](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) describes what mips are used for (interpolation) but mips can only be used on images that are power of 2 dimensions. The image you're trying to display is not power of 2 dimensions, it's 954 × 687 .

You have a few different options.

1. Download the image, edit to be power of 2 in both dimensions in a photo editing application. Then call `gl.generateMipmap` to generate mips for interpolation as described in [that page](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)
2. Copy the image to canvas that's a power of 2 in size then upload the canvas as a texture
3. Create a texture that's the next largest power of 2 then upload your image

   ```
   function nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(v) {
     return Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(v)));
   }

   const newWidth = nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(image.width);
   const newHeight = nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(image.height);

   // first make an empty texture of the new size
   const level = 0;
   const format = gl.RGBA;
   const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
   const border = 0;
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, format, newWidth, newHeight, border,
                   format, type, null);

   // then upload the image into the bottom left corner of the texture
   const xoffset = 0;
   const yoffset = 0;
   gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, type, image);

   // now because the texture is a power of 2 in both dimensions you can
   // generate mips and turn on maximum filtering

   gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   ```

You have a new issue though in all these cases which is that the image is now just using a portion of the texture. You'd have to adjust your texture coordinates either using [a texture matrix](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html) or by adjusting your texture coordinates directly.

```
  // compute needed texture coordinates to show only portion of texture
  var u = newWidth / image.width;
  var v = newHeight / image.height;

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    u, 0,
    0, v,
    0, v,
    u, 0,
    u, v,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  var image = new Image();
  requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(image, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Pneumothorax_CT.jpg")
  image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Pneumothorax_CT.jpg";
  image.onload = function() {
    render(image);
  }
}

function render(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  function nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(v) {
    return Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(v)));
  }

  const newWidth = nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(image.width);
  const newHeight = nearestGreaterOrEqualPowerOf2(image.height);

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Set a rectangle fit in the canvas at the same aspect as the image.
  const drawWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
  const drawHeight = canvas.clientWidth / drawWidth * image.height;
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, drawWidth, drawHeight);

  // compute needed texture coordinates to show only portion of texture
  var u = newWidth / image.width;
  var v = newHeight / image.height;

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    u, 0,
    0, v,
    0, v,
    u, 0,
    u, v,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Create a texture.
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // first make an empty texture of the new size
  {
    const level = 0;
    const format = gl.RGBA;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    const border = 0;
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, format, newWidth, newHeight, border,
                  format, type, null);

    // then upload the image into the bottom left corner of the texture
    const xoffset = 0;
    const yoffset = 0;
    gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, type, image);
  }
  
  // now because the texture is a power of 2 in both dimensions you can
  // generate mips and turn on maximum filtering

  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

  // lookup uniforms
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

  webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Clear the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Turn on the position attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

  // Turn on the teccord attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

  // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Draw the rectangle.
  var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
  var offset = 0;
  var count = 6;
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    x1, y1,
    x2, y1,
    x1, y2,
    x1, y2,
    x2, y1,
    x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();


// This is needed if the images are not on the same domain
// NOTE: The server providing the images must give CORS permissions
// in order to be able to use the image with WebGL. Most sites
// do NOT give permission.
// See: http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html
function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) {
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) {
    img.crossOrigin = "";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:700px; width:700px; overflow:scroll;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>


<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec2 a_position; 
  attribute vec2 a_texCoord; 
  uniform vec2 u_resolution; 
  varying vec2 v_texCoord; void main() { 
    // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0 
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution; 
    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2 
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0; 
    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace) 
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0; 
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1); 
    // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader 
    // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord; 
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
 
// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
 
// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
 
void main() {
   // Look up a color from the texture.
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
</script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want that images should be interpolated as it is zoomed for reference please check this link `http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/fnndsc/ami/tree/master/lessons/03#run`

Comment: Which is what I provided. Also your link is bad

Comment: thank you @gman will It work like that http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/fnndsc/ami/tree/master/lessons/03#run

Comment: I'm not sure what that link has to do with your question. That link is three.js not WebGL. I have no idea what three.js does with textures.

Comment: I need that kind of output of interpolation

Comment: Please @gman update your answer so that I can upvote it and I have a query to ask you about texSubimage2D

Answer (score 1):

Already really informative and good answers and comments here.

Also please take into account, that the link you provided using high quality images with high-res and excellent quality, at least with no compression artifacts.

Unpacked ~21mb in NIFTI Data Format.

using ami.js to uppack it:
https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami

Using the exampel by gman with a good image resolution that fits with your screen resolution, should give you a descend result.

Yes, their are some algorithms to fix a bad images quality and deal with image compression artifacts, but (and i don't whant to repeat the comments here) generally speaking once the information is lost, it is gone.